# How to print the changing values of QLCD Widget in PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm a bit new in PyQt4, I've been working on simple GUI which has an QDial and LCD Widget.I've used SIGNAL and SLOT technique,i.e when the QDial is changed it's value will be shown on the LCD Widget.
Similarly i want to print that LCD value in terminal everytime the QDial is changed.How am i supposed to do that?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(610, 404)
        MainWindow.setStatusTip(_fromUtf8(""))

        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.dial_1 = QtGui.QDial(self.centralWidget)
        self.dial_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 10, 101, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.dial_1.setFont(font)
        self.dial_1.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.dial_1.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.dial_1.setStatusTip(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.dial_1.setWhatsThis(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.dial_1.setAccessibleDescription(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.dial_1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.dial_1.setSingleStep(1)
        self.dial_1.setPageStep(10)
        self.dial_1.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.dial_1.setSliderPosition(0)
        self.dial_1.setWrapping(False)
        self.dial_1.setNotchTarget(3.7)
        self.dial_1.setNotchesVisible(True)
        self.dial_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dial_1"))
        self.lcdNumber_1 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralWidget)
        self.lcdNumber_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 40, 81, 41))
        self.lcdNumber_1.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.Panel)
        self.lcdNumber_1.setLineWidth(2)
        self.lcdNumber_1.setDigitCount(4)
        self.lcdNumber_1.setSegmentStyle(QtGui.QLCDNumber.Flat)
        self.lcdNumber_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_1"))
        self.label_1 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 100, 111, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_1"))
        self.dial_2 = QtGui.QDial(self.centralWidget)
        self.dial_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 120, 101, 91))
        self.dial_2.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.dial_2.setNotchesVisible(True)
        self.dial_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dial_2"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 210, 111, 17))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralWidget)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 150, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setFont(font)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.Panel)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setLineWidth(2)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setDigitCount(4)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setMode(QtGui.QLCDNumber.Dec)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setSegmentStyle(QtGui.QLCDNumber.Flat)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber_2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 611, 25))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dial_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.lcdNumber_1.display)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dial_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.lcdNumber_2.display)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Linear Velocity", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Angular Velocity", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you can connect own function which will use `print()` to display it in console.

Comment: It's worth to mention that, unless you're using a **very** old version of PyQt4 (which itself is quite old and considered obsolete, since [Py]Qt5 is out since almost 7 years), you can use the easier ["new-style signal and slot support"](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) introduced with PyQt5 (released more than 10 years ago), with the much simpler sintax `object.signal.connect(slot)`; in your case, `self.dial_1.valueChanged.connect(self.lcdNumber_1.display)`.

Comment: That said, if you're not stuck with [Py]Qt4 for serious reasons, I strongly suggest you to go straight with PyQt5. Also, you really shouldn't edit the output of pyuic, but use your own python file[s] for the logic of your program, leaving those generated GUI `py` files alone: if you need to edit a GUI you'll get a very hard time updating that code. More information/examples [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). It might seem complicated and overwhelming, but once you get how it works, it's worth the effort and really helps you to develop your applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect own function which gets value and use `print()` to display it

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dial_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.lcdNumber_1.display)
    # connect own function  
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dial_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.my_function)

def my_function(self, value):
    print(value)
```

The same with second `QDial`.

---

You can even use directly `print` without creating own function because `print` will gets value.

```
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dial_1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), print)
```

---

**EDIT:** as @musicamante mentioned in comment - this version

```
 SIGNAL(..., print)
```

will work only in Python 3 because `print` in Python 2 is not function.

Or you will have to use in Python 2

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: It's better to specify that the last part only works for Python 3. Since the OP is using the rather old PyQt4 we can suppose he/she might still be using Python 2 too.

Comment: [about your edit] or just create a method that acts as a slot, with any `print` statement you want in it :-)

Comment: @musicamante you could create answer and describe it better than me :)

Comment: A single, short and comprehensive answer is better than two answers that are almost identical, better for both the OP and whoever might read this question in the future. I strongly prefer to leave the editing to the answerer (third party editing should avoid altering the substance of an answer too much, no matter how useful that edit could be).